# Difference between "active top questions" and "active questions"

Tags: discussion, questions

What's the difference between the "active" tab of the home page (top questions), and the "active" tab of the questions button (all questions)?

I'm checking them, and they are showing a totally different list of questions in StackOverflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, they update at different times. I think the front page traditionally updates earlier, so sometimes you'll see a new question there before it shows up on the Questions tab.

Also, the front page does not display negatively voted questions, provided that it has refreshed by the time that the question is negative. See [voyager's comment on this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50195/more-medals-for-the-critics/50211#50211). A question that was just recently downvoted might still be on the front page, but by the next time the front page refreshes it should be gone.